# Is it relevant to use nested struct?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to define a class that has private struct and public struct.

**Private struct** is the struct that will only be used by the class (e.g. SNode), and I don't want it to be visible outside the class because I don't want it to be mistakenly used (e.g. new Node()). Thus, I reached to the idea to set it basically hidden.

**Public struct** is the struct that will be used outside (e.g. SKeyValuePair), and it will have a pointer to a SNode.

Code Example is below.

[Class Definition]

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
private:

    struct SNode
    {
        SNode* pParentNode;
        SNode* pLeftChildNode;
        SNode* pRightChildNode;

        ...
    };

public:

    A<T>()
    {
    }

    virtual ~A()
    {
    }

    struct SPair
    {
    private:
    public:

        SNode* pNode;
        unsigned long long ullKey;
        T value;

        ...
    };

    const SPair GetMinKeyPair()
    {
        return SPair(...);
    }

    const SPair GetNextMinKeyPair()
    {
        ...
        return SPair(...);
    }
    };
```

[Usage]

```
A a;
...
for (A::SPair pair = a.GetMinKeyPair(); pair.pNode != nullptr; pair = a.GetNextMinKeyPair())
{
    ...
}
```

**Q1. I wonder if this kind of nested struct (which public struct containing private struct pointer) should be avoided for some reason I currently don't know.**

**Q2. If there are reasons, I wonder what they are.**

Comment: What is under all those `...`?  Present a [mcve] so we don't have to guess at your constraints.

Comment: Why do you think nested struct type definitions should be avoided?

Comment: Note since the members of `SNode` are still public, they can still be used by anyone without naming the private type, as in `A::SPair pair = a.GetMinKeyPair(); auto* left = pair.pNode->pLeftChildNode;`. To avoid that, you could give `SNode` private members and make `A` a friend of `SNode`. Or possibly make `SNode` an "opaque type". It's even possible to `new` a node via tricks like `new std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(pair.pNode)>`; to avoid that, you could give `SNode` a private constructor and/or destructor.

Comment: Thanks for the comment 'Asteroids With Wings'. ```...``` was a mere ellipsis not to show details such as constructors and etc. Thanks for the link too!

Comment: Thanks for the comment KamilCuk. I do not think nested struct type definitions should be avoided. I am questioning 'Is adopting nested struct type definitions a bad idea?' in possibility perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the comment 'aschepler'. Wow. I never thought of using auto that way. Your comment is enlightening. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In general, this is not a bad way to do business.

It keeps the name `SNode<T>` private when it doesn't need to be public. (Though, as aschepler noted in comments, be aware that the type itself can still be used in full via `auto`; accessibility affects only *names*.)

So this is quite a neat way to organise things, and I do personally make use of nested types.

However, since `A` is a class *template*, you're going to have a copy of `SNode` for each `T` that you use. That's just how templates work. This means more code and a larger executable. For that reason, you might consider the more conventional approach of just putting the utility types in a namespace instead. Does it really matter whether people try to use them outside of `A<T>`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer 'Asteroids With Wings'. Yeah, having a copy of SNode for each T was another problem too. I thought of that conventional approach putting utility types in a namespace, but the reason I chose to put SPair in class A as public was namespace gives no protection against those who uses 'using namespace NAMESPACENAME'. I wanted to limit accessibility to things that are only necessary. But it seems there is no other way then...

Comment: Well, I wanted to limit people trying to do something unintended. Isn't typical use of Singleton is the case to explicitly limit creation of instance in similar sense? Because otherwise creating with new once and deleting it when it's needed would suffice.

Comment: Ultimately, it is possible to go too far in trying to "limit" people and "give protection" - why should people not be permitted to use the class if they want to? And if you really don't want them to, just put a comment "For internal use only" on it! Then move on ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! What a simple but powerful answer. You're right. I feel I have been in trap of going too far recently, delaying me from moving on. Thanks again.

Comment: @YoonSeokOH No problem; I understand the temptation.

Comment: @YoonSeokOH By the way, a common way to signal "internal use only" intention is to put your "private" class inside a namespace (at any level) called `detail`. If you do that, it'll be fairly well understood by many, though I'd still document this if you feel you need to, for those unfamiliar with the `detail` idiom.